# GET requests returns in 403 in R with httr, but 200 in python with requests

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I am trying to get release dates from US BLS, but I can't retrieve data  from the website when using `httr` R package. Here is the url:
https://www.bls.gov/bls/news-release/cpi.htm.

Code in R looks like this:

```
library(httr)

p = GET(
  "https://www.bls.gov/bls/news-release/cpi.htm",
  user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
)
status_code(p)
# [1] 403
```

but it works in Python with requests package:

```
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

p = requests.get("https://www.bls.gov/bls/news-release/cpi.htm", headers=headers)

p.status_code
# 200
```

Comment: The same code gives me `status_code(p)#
[1] 200`  Can you show package version

Comment: Hm, thats weird. Version of httr is ‘1.4.4’. I see there is 1.4.5., but don't beleive this is the reason ?

Comment: ok, maybe there is something weird on my end.  I used `packageVersion('httr')#
[1] ‘1.4.4’`

Comment: I would check which request headers are being sent with the successful python request and use the same ones with R.

Comment: I had to set 'Connection': 'keep-alive' in header. It works now. @RitchieSacramento, if you want ot set header in the answer I will accept it.